# Can you make a centralized build.gradle for many projects?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, microservices

I have a number of microservices, each service/project has its own build.gradle file, but I was wondering if I could just make a centralized build.gradle that could be pulled in to not only cut down on the amount of code in each project, but also to help take less time going through each service to update dependencies.

My initial thought is to maybe put something into JFrog's Artifactory and pull from there, but I was curious if there are already common practices out there for this.

Comment: Are you using a multi-project build? There is tremendous support in Gradle for sharing build code across projects.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you are talking about a shared environment of multiple projects, that may not be related in that sense, that they are built together. For such an environment you should indeed develop a plugin with a common codebase.

The easy solution for such a plugin is a so-called *script plugin*, which is basically a Gradle script just like `build.gradle`. It can be included via:

```
apply from: 'path/to/script.gradle'
// or
apply from: 'http://my.domain.tld/script.gradle'
```

The more advanced but therefor more complicated solution would be the development of a *binary plugin*. You could provide the plugin via any repository and include it like any other Gradle plugin.

Comment: You are missing a `:` after your from, `apply from: 'script'`

Comment: @Winter: Fixed !

Answer (score 0):

One option is [blowdryer](https://github.com/diffplug/blowdryer).  First, factor out your common code and config files into a separate git repository ([blowdryer-diffplug](https://github.com/diffplug/blowdryer-diffplug) is a good example).

In the project you want to consume those scripts and config files, you point the build to a specific commit or tag in that repository:

```
// settings.gradle
blowdryerSetup {
    github 'diffplug/blowdryer-diffplug', 'tag', '2.0.0' // can also use commit SHA
    //devLocal '../blowdryer-diffplug' // for local development
}
```

Now, throughout your build, you can slurp any file you want using the chinese character for dry (干). e.g.

```
apply from: 干.file('someScript.gradle')
somePlugin {
  configFile 干.file('somePluginConfig.xml')
  configProp 干.prop('propfile', 'key') // returns value of 'key' in 'propfile.properties'
}
```

You don't have to publish the scripts in a separate repository, you can also just point the project [to itself](https://github.com/diffplug/blowdryer-diffplug/blob/ca0e5d37b9323f837ab7d3d610380f42c5bfc508/settings.gradle#L16-L19), and it's still handy because you don't have to worry about relative vs absolute paths as much.  It also has some optional tooling that helps with structuring these scripts, which you can learn more about in the [project's readme](https://github.com/diffplug/blowdryer#script-plugins).